OpenAI Assistant now answering from specific file
It's answering from file which is fine. But I have many Assistant, and the every user will answer from a selected file.
I have two assistants (1, A2), and three files ( F1, F2, F3). A1 will answer from F1, and A2 will answer from F1 and F2.
How to achieve that?
const askQuestion = async (fileId, question, retryCount = 0) => {
    // Constructing the prompt for OpenAI API
    const prompt = `Answer the question based on the file content (ID: ${fileId}): ${question}`;

    try {
        // Sending request to OpenAI API
        const response = await axios.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', {
            model: "gpt-4o",
            messages: [
                { role: "system", content: "You are a helpful assistant." },
                { role: "user", content: question }
            ],
            prompt: prompt, // Include the constructed prompt
            max_tokens: 100 // Optional: You can adjust this as needed
        }, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${OPENAI_API_KEY}`
            }
        });

        return response.data.choices[0].text;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        if (error.response && error.response.status === 429 && retryCount < 3) {
            const backoffTime = exponentialBackoff(retryCount);
            // console.log(`Rate limit exceeded. Retrying after ${backoffTime}ms...`);
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, backoffTime));
            return askQuestion(fileId, question, retryCount + 1); // Retry recursively
        } else {
            throw error; // Throw if retries are exhausted or for non-rate limit errors
        }
    }
};

app.post('/ask', async (req, res) => {
    const { fileId, question } = req.body;

    // Check if fileId and question are provided
    if (!fileId || !question) {
        return res.status(400).send('fileId and question are required');
    }

    try {
        const answer = await askQuestion(fileId, question);
        res.json({ answer });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error asking question:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to get response from OpenAI API' });
    }
});

